# JDBC Connection url to AWS

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, derby

I have a running instance in AWS and a derby database in `/home/ubuntu/mydata` . Is it possible to connect to that database from my desktop application if I write my jdbc url like like this : `jdbc:derby://<aws_ip_address>:1527/home/ubuntu/mydata;create=true` ? Basically this works in local area network fine. I am using `c3p0` for connection pulling. If it is not possible, how should I connect the the database?

Edit: I've also added the security group in AWS

[image]

Comment: Does the AWS instance have a public IP?

Comment: Otherwise you can use a VPN or use SSH port forwarding.

Comment: @Michael. Yes. AWS has a public IP.

Comment: If there is a public IP, perhaps try it out first!

Comment: @ShivamPuri I tried. does not help.

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara Just to make sure I understand the setup correctly: your Derby database runs in AWS and you want to connect to it from your local machine?

Comment: @Michael. Yes. My derby database will run in AWS and I want to connect to it from my local machine.

Comment: What error do you get? Can you 'ping' the AWS IP address from your local machine? Can you 'telnet IP 1527' from your local machine?